# NetBeans GUI builder: "loading..." message

Tags: java, linux, swing, netbeans

Sample project from the NetBeans tutorials set contains only one Swing form (empty JFrame), compiles and runs fine, but I can't change layout of the form and add elements in it with the NetBeans GUI buider since it shows only empty placeholder with single "loading..." message. Any clues how to fix it would be highly appreciated.

Kubuntu 12.04, Openjdk 1.7, NetBeans 7.0.1 with active GUI designer plugin.

Log file contains an error

`SEVERE [org.openide.util.RequestProcessor]: Error in RequestProcessor org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner$PreLoadTask`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

KNOWN BUG in Designer marked as done (Netbeans 7.0.1 GUI editor is not loading).

Get a new version from netbeans.

Seems to be the same problem.

reported:
...
All my projects are using SWING-components, and when I'm clicking
on "Design"  switcher, in order to make changes in GUI, it is showing label
"loading" and I get following error:
...

Answer (score 0):

I have very similar problem with NetBeans-7.2 on Gentoo system (the only difference is another error in the log: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal`). The solution is to install `dev-java/batik` package and start NetBeans with

```
netbeans-7.2 -cp:a /usr/share/batik-1.7/lib/batik-ext.jar
```

These extra arguments can be added to `netbeans_default_options` in the `/etc/netbeans-7.2/netbeans.conf` to make a permanent fix. More information can be found [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=653915) and [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7233044.html).